# $\binom{b}{2}+\binom{b-p}{2} ≥ \binom{(b+1)/2}{2}+\binom{(b-1)/2}{2} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Prove that:
>
> $\binom{b}{2}+\binom{b-p}{2} ≥\binom{(b+1)/2}{2}+\binom{(b-1)/2}{2}$
>
> with $b≥ p$ are integer and b is odd

**My attempt**

By convexity $\binom{b}{2}+\binom{b-p}{2} ≥\binom{b/2}{2}+\binom{b/2}{2}$
(We use the real extension of binomial coefficient). From here how can I continue? Thanks for help.

Comment: In the worst case,  $p=b$, and the $\binom{b-p}{2}$ disappears; you can prove $\binom b2 \ge \binom{(b+1)/2}{2} + \binom{(b-1)/2}{2}$ just by algebra...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be derived from the more general fact that ${m\choose 2} + {n\choose 2} \leq {m+n\choose 2}$ for any positive integer $m,n$.

The above fact can be seen by the situation where you have $m$ red balls and $n$ blue balls. ${m+n\choose 2}$ is the way to choose two balls without any restriction. ${m\choose 2} + {n\choose 2}$ is the way to choose two balls where the balls have to be both red or both blue.

Answer (score 1):

We can also prove that

$\displaystyle\binom mh+\binom nh\leqslant\binom{m+n}h\;$ for any $\;m,n,h\in\Bbb N\,\land\,h\leqslant m,n\,.$

**Proof :**

It could be proved by applying the same method of @cr001 user’s, but there is also another possible proof which is the following one:

$\begin{align}\displaystyle\binom mh\!+\!\binom nh&=\left[\binom m1\!+\!\binom n1\right]\prod\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}\left[\dfrac{\binom m{i+1}\!+\!\binom n{i+1}}{\binom mi\!+\!\binom ni}\right]=\\[3pt]&=\left[\binom m1\!+\!\binom n1\right]\prod\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}\left[\dfrac{\binom mi\frac{m-i}{i+1}\!+\!\binom ni\frac{n-i}{i+1}}{\binom mi\!+\!\binom ni}\right]\leqslant\\[3pt]&\leqslant\left[\binom m1\!+\!\binom n1\right]\prod\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}\left[\dfrac{\binom mi\frac{m+n-i}{i+1}\!+\!\binom ni\frac{m+n-i}{i+1}}{\binom mi\!+\!\binom ni}\right]\!=\\[3pt]&=\left[\dfrac{m+n-0}{0+1}\right]\prod\limits_{i=1}^{h-1}\left[\dfrac{m+n-i}{i+1}\right]=\\[3pt]&=\prod\limits_{i=0}^{h-1}\left[\dfrac{m+n-i}{i+1}\right]=\dfrac{(m\!+\!n)!}{h!(m\!+\!n\!-h)!}=\binom{m\!+\!n}h\,.\end{align}$

---

For $\,m=\dfrac{b+1}2\,,\;$ $n=\dfrac{b-1}2\,,\;$ $h=2\,,\;$ we get that

$\displaystyle\binom{\frac{b+1}2}2+\binom{\frac{b-1}2}2\leqslant\binom b2\leqslant\binom b2+\binom{b-p}2$

which is the original user’s inequality.